# How much can you trust a (banking) site after it spams you?

Tags: spam, fraud, financial

How much can you trust a company that send you spam ?

Many people, after registering with `Moneybookers`(`Skrill`) started to receive spam that included their real name (as inputted in Moneybookers registration) in the subject of the message, messages that mostly involve ads of gambling sites, the links to "stop send spam" or "unsubscribe" do not work.

A bit later they started to receive scam messages, involving "your fedex package has arrived!" kind of message.

Google shows that this issue is a known issue, and some were 100% sure its because of moneybookers, due to using unique mail address for moneybookers only.

However, ...

No body have accused moneybookers of steeling money or similar, or at least I didn't hear of any of that. (other than the regular account steeling among different banking services).

Moneybookers still seems to be used by many major websites like ebay, and still recommended as first alternative after paypal.

There could be allot of people out there using it, and receiving spam, and not knowing that the spam is coming from using them.

So, How much can it be trusted ?

Comment: This doesn't have an answerable question. If you could edit the question we may be able to reopen. Trust, in the sense you have used, is very subjective.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I have removed the part saying "For some users, where paypal is not an option, moneybookers is the only option.", I think it changes the meaning a bit. Hope thats enough to be re-opened.

Comment: It seems like a real question to me and one I've often wondered. I've changed my personal bank over this sort of thing. Then again, I don't post questions here because I don't feel like my understanding of the exact rules for questions is sufficient to avoid having my post closed, and I don't know the world of commercial banks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have sent a new, specific email address to a company, and then you begin to receive spam on that address, then you have proof that either they gave or sold you address to a third party, or your address was stolen from them.

That some big companies sell users' addresses is common enough, and predates the Internet; postal services and phone companies have done it for decades. Apparently, it can be legal, if you are a big enough company... That's still quite uncourteous and morally questionable. But the alternative is worse: if the addresses were *stolen* from them, then this means that their machines got hacked, so their security sucks, and you really do not want to give them custody of your money.

If you have to choose between a wolf and a sheep, take the wolf; the wolf, at least, knows what is going on.

Of course, once the address is sold, it can be resold, so Moneybookers themselves would have no way to prevent the lowest grade spammers from using it. They would not send the spam themselves, this is a way too small business for a big financial player to lower itself to that level.

According to [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moneybookers), Moneybookers (rebranded as Skrill) is London-based and operates under the [FSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Services_Authority) and EU regulations. This means at least some basic level of customer protection. I would say that you could do worse than using their services. Anyway, as you say:

> For some users, where paypal is not an option, moneybookers is the only option.

so, if you have no choice, where is the question ?